# How to define a set of decision variables in ascending order? (TypeError: Cannot convert a linear constraint to boolean: S1 <= S2)

Tags: cplex, docplex

Good day to you.
I would like to define a set of decision variables S for docplex.mp in cplex in ascending order, from the smallest to the largest value of S).
When I tried to use the following code, it seems incorrect. Could anyone let me know how could I define the decision variable for S, please?
Thank you in advance.

'''

```
 S= [[S1] ,                                                                                                                                                                           
    [S2] ,                                                                                                                                                                                 
    [S3],                                                                                                                                                                                   
    [S4],                                                                                                                                                                                  
    [S5],                                                                                                                                                                                   
    [S6]]
```

'''

```
      Total_T = 6
      S = np.empty((Total_T,1), dtype= object)
      for k in range(Total_T):
            S[k] = mdl.continuous_var(lb= 0, ub= inf, name='S' + str(k+1))
      
      for k in range(Total_T):
      if S is not None:
            mdl.add_constraint(S[k]<= S[k + 1] <= S[k + 2] <= S[k + 3] <= S[k + 4] <= 
                                S[Total_T - 1] <= S[k] + obj_lambda)
```

'''

```
 Error Message:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/pknu/Documents/Research/project/MILP Correct 19 July 2022.py", line 152, in 
  <module>
    mdl.add_constraint(S[k]<= S[k + 1] <= S[k + 2] <= S[k + 3] <= S[k + 4] <= S[Total_T - 1] 
   <= S[k] + obj_lambda)
  File "C:\Users\pknu\anaconda3\envs\env-cplex\lib\site-packages\docplex\mp\constr.py", line 
  101, in __bool__
    self._no_linear_ct_in_logical_test_error()  # pragma: no cover
  File "C:\Users\pknu\anaconda3\envs\env-cplex\lib\site-packages\docplex\mp\constr.py", line 
   549, in _no_linear_ct_in_logical_test_error
    raise TypeError(msg)

 TypeError: Cannot convert a linear constraint to boolean: S1 <= S2
```

'''

Answer (score 2):

You should write your x<=y<=z with many constraints as can be seen in [example](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithdocplex/blob/main/xyzconstraint.py)

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='xyz')


x = mdl.continuous_var(name='x')
y = mdl.continuous_var(name='y')
z = mdl.continuous_var(name='z')

decisionVars=[x,y,z]

mdl.add_constraint(z<=4)

#mdl.add_constraint(x<=y<=z, 'ctxyz') does not work

mdl.add_constraint(x<=y, 'ctxy')
mdl.add_constraint(y<=z, 'ctyz')


mdl.maximize(x+y+z)

mdl.solve()

for v in decisionVars:
    print(v.name," = ",v.solution_value)
```